# MVC3, Why does date in JQuery JSON appears like this? /Date(1324512000000)/

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am sending date values from C# application via JSON but instead of a standard date, it appears in this format /Date(1324512000000)/

Can anyone please tell me how to send it from C# in the format it expects? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON doesn't recognize c#'s datetime object.  You should send it back as a string by calling .toString on your datetime variable in your controller.

Comment: requiring client side to parse a date can be bad for cross browser compatability.

Comment: i found that sending date.toshortdatestring() was the best option

Answer (score 3):

That's how the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) is handling dates:

> Date object, represented in JSON as "/Date(number of ticks)/". The
>   number of ticks is a positive or negative long value that indicates
>   the number of ticks (milliseconds) that have elapsed since midnight 01
>   January, 1970 UTC.

You could convert this into a javascript Date like this:

```
var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
```

Comment: how do i send from  C# in the form it expects?

Comment: should i cast it to a string?

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker, no, in C# you don't need to do anything. In your controller action you simply `return Json(new { SomeDate = DateTime.Now });`. Then on the client you could invoke this controller action using AJAX and in the success callback if you wanted to manipulate the date as a javascript Date object you could do what I showed in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

That's just how dates are expressed in JSON.  See here for how to parse it back into something useful in javascript: [How do I format a Microsoft JSON date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-a-json-date)

Comment: Why not have the server, which is way more efficient at this type of operation, handle the conversion?